# Highlight row of form when input is focussed

Tags: focus, mootools, highlighting

I have the following piece of Mootools 1.11 code (not upgradable as this is within Joomla), which I want to highlight the form row, when an item within it is focussed. However, this doesn't work. I need to know how to access the parent div of the form item.

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    var list = $$('#ChronoContact_lensorder div.formrow');
    list.each(function(element) {

var fx = new Fx.Styles(element, {duration:200, wait:false});

element.addEvent('focus', function(){
    fx.start({
        'background-color': '#e6f0f2',
        color: '#FFF'
    });
});

element.addEvent('focus', function(){
    fx.start({
        'background-color': '#FFF',
        'color': '#2F9AD0'
    });
});

}); 
});
```

HTML is:

```
<div class="formrow"> 
<label for="ud">Uncut Diameter:</label> 
<input type="text" id="ud" name="ud" /> 
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looking for the `<div>`s, you might want to look for the actual `<input>` using `var list = $$('#ChronoContact_lensorder div.formrow input');` Then refer to the parent using the `.getParent()` method when necessary, like this:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    var list = $$('#ChronoContact_lensorder div.formrow input');
    list.each(function(element) {

var fx = new Fx.Styles(element.getParent(), {duration:200, wait:false});

element.addEvent('focus', function(){
    fx.start({
        'background-color': '#e6f0f2',
        color: '#FFF'
    });
});

element.addEvent('blur', function(){
    fx.start({
        'background-color': '#FFF',
        'color': '#2F9AD0'
    });
});

}); 
});
```

Untested code. Note that the second event is now `blur` instead of `focus`, or else both events will fire at the same time and might revert each other's effects!

Comment: Thanks MvanGeest. That's the sort of thing I was after. Needs a bit of tweaking for textareas and checkboxes/radio buttons, but that's more like it.

Nice one